# C# Byte Array of lists (or dictionaries) with equal content are not equal

Tags: list, dictionary, byte, arrays, equality

I have two Lists with the same content. The first one had added three items and removed one again. The second one had added only the remaining two items. Then I converted both to byte array, but the byte array are not equal. They differ in one byte.
Is there a way to have two "equal" lists with equal byte arrays independent of performed operations?

I need this for saving the list to a text file with a RSA signature included. But I can't have a valide signature if the list in memory, with operations performed on it in  the past, is not equal to the new generated list from the content of the text file.

In my Application i use dictionaries instead of lists, but it's the same behaviour.

Here is my test code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> one = new List<string>();

        one.Add("hallo");
        one.Add("hallo1");
        one.Remove("hallo1");
        one.Add("hallo1");

        byte[] test = Program.ObjectToByteArray(one);
        Console.WriteLine(test.Length);



        List<string> two = new List<string>();

        two.Add("hallo");
        two.Add("hallo1");

        byte[] test1 = Program.ObjectToByteArray(two);
        Console.WriteLine(test1.Length);

        bool areEqual = false;
        int count = 0;
        if (test.Length == test1.Length)
        {
            areEqual = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
            {
                if (test[i] != test1[i])
                {
                    areEqual = false;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Are they equal?: " + areEqual.ToString() + ": " + count.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

**Edit:**
In my application i will have a class like this:

```
[Serializable]
class MetaDataModel
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> readers;
    private Dictionary<string, string> writers;
    public bool IsDirty { get; set; }
    public string PublicReaderKey { get; set; }
    public string CipherPrivateReaderKey { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Readers
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.readers == null)
                this.readers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            return this.readers;
        }
        set
        {
            this.readers = value;
        }
    }
    public string PublicWriterKey { get; set; }
    public string CipherPrivateWriterKey { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Writers
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.writers == null)
                this.writers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            return this.writers;
        }
        set
        {
            this.writers = value;
        }
    }
    public byte[] Signature { get; set; }
}
```

And want it use like this:

```
MetaDataModel metaData = new MetaDataModel()

//filling the properties here

metaData.Signature = RSASignatureGenerator.HashAndSignData(this.ObjectToByteArray(metaData), this.rsaKeyPair[0]);
```

Comment: Can't you use [`List.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Oh ok, thanks, that would work for this example, but in my application i have an object with two lists and further properties. The signature is for the whole object. So this is not very handy for generating and validating the signature.

Comment: I think I have to write my own ObjectToByteArray(Object obj) method. Than I'm abel to control which bytes are signed. But I have no idea how that methot can look like at the moment.